# Unable to change Username

Tags: 12.04

I have been using Ubuntu since 3 years, I have learnt a lot from it. I loaded ubuntu and never formatted, but now I wanted to rename my username by usermod -l Atif Malik Manchester but im unable to. how can I do that?

Comment: did you put "sudo" in front of the command? And would it not be easier to do this from gui "users"? Oh and are those 3 names? Should be 2 and no spaces ;)

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. Yes I tried using command and gui. I want to rename it to "Atif Malik Manchester" (my name). Can this be possible(with space)? I doubt it a virus issue or something else, because often i get some unexpected errors.

Comment: Technically you can circumvent spaces by adding quotes: "Atif Malik Manchester" but I have a feeling not all software will support spaces in a username. I can not find prove... all I find are people stating "do not use spaces" but no source or explanation. Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all read the `man usermod`:

"The name of the user will be changed from LOGIN to NEW_LOGIN. Nothing else is changed. In particular, the user's home directory name should probably be changed manually to reflect the new login name."

What you are trying to do is quite wrong. Your new username contains spaces, and `usermod` will interpret it as multiple arguments. Also you cannot change it from current user. You have to log in from recovery console and after:

```
usermod -l AtifMalikManchester OldUsername
usermod -d /home/AtifMalikManchester -m OldUsername
```